# Django limit_choices_to for multiple fields with "or" condition

Tags: django, limit-choices-to

I am trying to limit choices for a field, by checking values of the two columns, `share_holder` and `distributor`. If either of them is true, then I want that choice.

With the below version, I only get choices satisfying both conditions `('share_holder': True AND 'distributor': True)`.

```
limit_choices_to={'share_holder': True, 'distributor': True}
```

However, I need choices for `('share_holder': True OR 'distributor': True)`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use Q objects to achieve this.

```
from django.db.models import Q


limit_choices_to=Q(share_holder=True) | Q(distributor=True)
```

Official docs on [ForeignKey.limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to)

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked perfect. Could Q objects be used for filtering a field based on other fields of same object. For example, after first field value is selected (such as "animals"), then in second field I only want to show list of animals, not all living things.

Comment: Q objects is really powerful for complex lookups.
Unfortunately I've failed to understand your requirement. If you please tell me little bit detail I'll try to construct the queryset.

Comment: assume my object is something like class product() with fields of product_class, and product_name. Once user select the product class value, the choices of the product_name should be filtered by the selected product_class.

Comment: For such situation you may use chain filters like  
`Product.objects.filter(product_class='class_value').filter(product_name='name_value')`  
[django-filter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter) is handy package for regular filtering needs.

Comment: To clarify my question, posted a new question  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238500/django-limit-choices-to-by-same-objects-field-value). Having difficulty to get the value of the current instance.