# limit_choices_to with A or B logic

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've got a model named MyUser with a user_type field which can be of the following different user types

> USER_TYPE_STUDENT
>
> USER_TYPE_TEACHER
>
> USER_TYPE_DIRECTOR

In one of the models, I've got the following field

```
student = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, null=True, related_name='requests',
                            limit_choices_to={'user_type': MyUser.USER_TYPE_STUDENT}, ...)
```

As you can read, it uses

```
limit_choices_to={'user_type': MyUser.USER_TYPE_STUDENT}
```

Thing is, in a OneToOneField field (students_or_teachers), I would like to declare that field is limited to user_type USER_TYPE_STUDENT or USER_TYPE_TEACHER.

How can that be done?

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30181079/django-limit-choices-to-for-multiple-fields-with-or-condition

Comment: I've seen that before. In that specific case the OR is used between different fields, instead of different possible choices of the same field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `__in` lookup:

```
limit_choices_to = {
    "user_type__in": (MyUser.USER_TYPE_STUDENT, MyUser.USER_TYPE_TEACHER)
    }
```